# Where should shared partials go?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I have multiple views, but they are supposed to share the same partial (Footer and ad bars for example), where should these shared partials go?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would create a shared folder in views and put all my shared partials in it. You can call the partial like this:

```
<%= render 'shared/partialname' %>
```

Answer (score 0):

While creating a partial you have to put underscore infront of the name of file.

like `footer inside a layout folder -> _footer.html.erb`

Then you have to specify at particular location by using this statement :

```
<%= render 'layout/footer' %>
```